# What does 'Samples' mean in perf output?

Tags: profile, sample, perf

I used linux perf to profile my program and I can not understand the result.

```
10.5%    2     fun     ..........
      |
      |- 80% - ABC
      |        call_ABC
      -- 20% - DEF
               call_DEF
```

The above example means that 'fun' has two samples and contributes 10.5% overheads,

and 80% of them is called from ABC, 20% from DEF. Am I right?

Now we have only two samples, then how does 'perf' calculate the fraction of ABC and DEF?

Why aren't they 50%? dose 'perf' use additional information?

Comment: Could you please provide the syntax / options you used to execute perf?

Answer (score 0):

> The above example means that 'fun' has two samples and contributes 10.5% overheads,

Yes, this part of `perf report -g -n` shows that 2 of 19 samples (2 is 10.5% of 19) was in the foo function itself. 17 other samples were sampled in the other function.

I just reproduced your code with recent gcc (`-static -O3 -fno-inline -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g`) and perf (`perf record -e cycles:u -c 500000 -g ./test12968422` for low resolution samples or `-c 5000` for high resolution). Now perf has bit different weight rules, but idea should be same. When there is only 2 samples for the program and both are in the `foo`, call-graph (`perf report -n -g callee`) is 50 for every of call_DEF/_ABC (no additional information). This program actually had 86% of runtime in foo, 61% of them when called from ABC,  25% of 86 when called from DEF:

```
100%  2  fun
 - fun
   + 50% call_DEF
   + 50% call_ABC
```

What are the kind of additional information perf may use to reconstruct more information? I think it can be either self weight of call_DEF and call_ABC; or it can be frequency of "call_ABC->foo" and "call_DEF->foo" parts of callchain in the all sample call stacks.

With perf from linux kernel versions 4.4 / 4.10 I can't reproduce your situation. I added different amount of self work in the call_ABC and call_DEF. Both of them just calls foo for fixed amount of work. Now I have 19 samples of `-e cycles:u -c 54000 -g`, 13 for call_ABC, 2 for call_DEF, 2 for fun (and 2 in some random functions):

```
  Children  Self  Samples Symbol
       74%  68%        13 [.] call_ABC
       16%  10.5%       2 [.] call_DEF
     10.5%  10.5%       2 [.] fun
    - fun
      + 5.26% call_ABC
      + 5.26% call_DEF
```

So, try newer version of perf, not from epoch of 3.2 Linux kernels.

First source of `fun` only work, inequal shares when called from ABC and from DEF:

```
#define g 100000
int a[2+g];

void fill_a(){
    a[0]=0;
    for(int f=0;f<g;f++)
        a[f+1]=f;
}

int fun(int b)
{
    while(a[b])
        b=a[b]; 
    return b;
}

int call_ABC(int b)
{
    int d = b;
    b = fun(d);
    return d-b;
}

int call_DEF(int b)
{
    int e = b;
    b = fun(e);
    return e+b;
}

int main()
{
    int c,d;
    fill_a();
    c=call_ABC(100000);
    c=call_DEF(45000);
    return c+d; 
}
```

Second source of inequal work in ABC and DEF with equal small work in fun:

```
#define g 100000
int a[2+g];

void fill_a(){
    a[0]=0;
    for(int f=0;f<g;f++)
        a[f+1]=f;
}

int fun(int b)
{
    while(a[b])
        b=a[b]; 
    return b;
}

int call_ABC(int b)
{
    int d = b;
    while(a[d])
        d=a[d]; 
    b = fun(5000);
    return d-b;
}

int call_DEF(int b)
{
    int e = b;
    while(a[e])
        e=a[e]; 
    b = fun(5000);
    return e+b;
}

int main()
{
    int c,d;
    fill_a();
    c=call_ABC(100000);
    c=call_DEF(20000);
    return c+d; 
}
```